# didSelectRowAtIndexPath Using Viiew Delegate NOT working On iPad IOS SDK 8, any ideas?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, ios8, didselectrowatindexpath

Pretty basic code that has been working fine in prior versions has stopped working. didSelectRowAtIndexPath stops responding after select first one or two objects from core data fetch. No warnings, errors, or freeze, just no response.  Same code without view delegate working fine on iPhone.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = self.payment.name;
    self.paymentNameTextField.text = self.payment.name;

    [paymentView setDelegate:self];
    [paymentView setDataSource:self];
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SimpleCell *cell = (SimpleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    payment = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.nameBasicLabel.text =self.payment.name;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.payment = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.paymentNameTextField.text = self.payment.name;
    [self viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "using view delegate"? What class is this code in. What class is the paymentNameTextField in? You should edit your question to put this code in its context.

Comment: [paymentView setDelegate:self];

Comment: [paymentView setDelegate:self];  [paymentView setDataSource:self];There is a table view within a view controller.  A master detail (email) type view with the table and the detail within the sane view.  As selection of a row shows the detail in the same view.